# Code returning NAN

Tags: javascript, time

I wrote some javascript in hopes of outputting time as `hh:mm`  (EG: `15:45`)

However my code is returning Nan:Nan

```
var timer = 24;
var time1 = new Date();
time1.setHours(time1.getHours + (6));
time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes());
document.write(time1.toString("hh:mm"));
```

Can someone help me understand why this isn't working as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getHours` member is a function not a value.  Hence you're multiplying a number by a method and getting `NaN`.  Make sure to invoke the method

```
time1.setHours(time1.getHours() + (6));
```

Comment: As another question, this string still doesn't return quite right, it returns 18:47:26 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)  How do I get rid of everything after the 18:47?

Comment: @Damien.Bell take a look at this answer.  It should cover what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `time1.getHours` is a method. When you add 6 to a method, the result is `NaN`. You need to actually call it:

```
time1.setHours(time.getHours() + 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.write(time1.getHours()+":"+time1.getMinutes());` instead of it.